# How can I compare private member variables of different classes without using inheritance/getters/reflection?

Tags: java, interface, composition

I had to create two different classes with similar member variables and methods, excepting two methods that one of them doesn't have. So I decided to create an instance of the incomplete class into the other class in order not to have duplicate code.

So they look like this:

```
public class Beast{
    private int speed;
    //other variables & methods
    ...    
}
```

&

```
public class Hero{
    private int speed;
    //other variables
    ...
    Beast beast = new Beast();
    ...
}
```

How can I compare the `speed` variable of a `Beast` instance with the one of a `Hero` instance  **without using any sort of inheritance between the two classes, getters or reflection**? (maybe interfaces would help me, I don't know since I'm still in my early Java learning phase)

Comment: If both classes are under your control, I would strongly recommend a common interface or getter methods to give you read access to both.

Comment: Since it is part of a problem that I was asked to solve, I am in control of everything that happens. Getters are not an option, since I'm not allowed to used them.

Comment: Then do the simplest thing that can possibly work.  If you're just learning Java, don't fight the idiom.  See how other people have done it and follow suit.

Comment: I was asked to solve this problem in my internship. My supervisor asks for design and composition.

Comment: Your supervisor is an idiot, this exercise is anywhere from impossible to purpose-less

Comment: wouldn't this defeat the purpose for the principle of encapsulation? for solutions, i don't believe i would ever do this, but, perhaps static inner classes acting as getters/setters or interface between the two classes or use some external technology such as javascript engine to allow the two classes to communicate, but if you're really wild and determined, i suppose you can use an api to load the jvm, freeze the program, grab the fields of that member variable and dynamically change it or swap it with a temporary clone?

Answer (score 1):

If this is just some kind of a puzzle, here are a couple ways to do this without inheritance, getters or reflection.

1. Nested classes can access the private variables of their enclosing classes, as well as other nested classes in the same scope.

   ```
   class Outer {
       public static class Hero { private int speed; }
       public static class Beast { private int speed; }
   }
   ```

   In that example, `Hero` and `Beast` are now able to access each others' private `speed` variables. This means that the `Hero` class can just do `this.speed == aBeast.speed`, or however it is that you want to compare.
2. Using parameter passing.

   ```
   public class Beast {
       private int speed;

       public boolean isSpeedEqualTo(int speed) {
           return this.speed == speed;
       }
   }
   ```

   Then e.g. `Hero` can say `aBeast.isSpeedEqualTo(this.speed)`.

However, using getters makes more sense, and it seems like the `speed` variable should also be declared in a superclass which both `Hero` and `Beast` extend.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare `private` fields of instances of thse distinct classes if you don't provide a getter in the composed class.

Without reflection, you have broadly two alternatives :

- making the field `public`, which is often a bad practice
- introducing a comparison method in `Hero` to compare speed and provide a getter in the other class. You don't need to provide the getter in `Hero` as private fields are accessible within the instance methods of the class.

For the second way, it could look like :

```
public class Beast{    
   private int speed;

   public Beast(int speed){
     ...
   }
   public int getSpeed(){
     return speed;
  }
}

public class Hero {    
   private int speed;
   private Beast beast;

   public Hero (int speed, Beast beast){
     ...
   }

   // just an example to use speed from the both instances
   public boolean isMoreFast(){
     return speed > beast.getSpeed();
   }

}
```

You can now do :

```
Beast beast = new Beast(beastSpeed);
Hero hero = new Hero(heroSpeed, beast);
boolean isHeroFaster = hero.isMoreFast();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can not do this without inheritance, getters or reflection.

When you declare a private variable, this variable can only be directly accessed within its own class.

Below the oracle documentation:

> In the spirit of encapsulation, it is common to make fields private. This means that they can only be directly accessed from the Bicycle class. We still need access to these values, however. This can be done **indirectly by adding public methods** that obtain the field values for us.

Oracle Documentation: [Java Access Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: Wrong, you can always get around it with reflection.

Comment: My answer was: I believe that you can no do this **without** inheritance, getters and reflection, please more attention before say that answer is wrong. @duffymo

Answer (score -1):

Use static keyword before int .

Static int speed .

With help of static keyword you don't need to create object of class, you can access it with like

ClassName.variable name

Comment: That speed variable is obviously an instance variable, not a class variable, so it has to be non-static.